# Excel Shows Junk Characters

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written a script in outlook to export Selected Email to excel.

Can anybody help me to configure Excel or what change might be required in my code so that it doesn't show Junk Characters like below screenshot?

[image]

In one PC it shows correctly but not in other.

Following is my code:

```
Const ExcelPath = "c:\outlook\outlook_emails.xlsx"

Sub Export_To_Excel()
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oMail = GetCurrentItem

    If oMail Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No or Invalid Item selected", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo Err_H

    ' Get Email Info
    Email = GetSmtpAddress(oMail)
    Body = Replace(oMail.Body, Chr(9), vbCrLf)
    Subject = Replace(oMail.Subject, Chr(9), vbCrLf)

    ' Export to Excel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath)
    Set oWS = oWB.Sheets(1)
    LastRow = oWS.Cells(oWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(-4162).Row + 1
    oWS.Cells(LastRow, "A") = Format(LastRow - 1, "###")
    oWS.Cells(LastRow, "B") = Email
    oWS.Cells(LastRow, "D") = Body
    oWS.Cells(LastRow, "C") = Subject
    oWS.Cells.RowHeight = 17
    oWS.UsedRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    oWS.UsedRange.Font.Size = 8
    oWB.Close True
    Set oExcel = Nothing: Set oWS = Nothing: Set oWB = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully exported Email Info exported to Excel", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

Err_H:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Something Went Wrong"
    Set oExcel = Nothing: Set oWS = Nothing: Set oWB = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function GetCurrentItem() As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application

    On Error GoTo Err_H
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)

        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

        Case Else
            Set GetCurrentItem = Nothing
    End Select
    Exit Function

Err_H:
    Set GetCurrentItem = Nothing
End Function

Private Function GetSmtpAddress(ByVal item As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    Dim sAddress As String
    Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim exUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    If UCase$(item.SenderEmailType) = "EX" Then
        Set recip = oNS.CreateRecipient(item.SenderEmailAddress)
        Set exUser = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
        sAddress = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Else
        sAddress = item.SenderEmailAddress
    End If
    GetSmtpAddress = sAddress
    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
End Function
```

Link to a bigger Image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwjl0SErKySTMmkwZ21zOXhJSEU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @PortlandRunner: I have posted a bigger image. Pls have a look now. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe adding line(s) `Body = Replace( Body, ,"|","")` and/or `Body = Application.Clean(Body)` might help.

Comment: Sorry I still can't read it well, guess my eyes are getting old.  I'm guessing your getting key returns.  You can replace these with "" to remove them if that's the case.

Comment: @PortlandRunner: Here is the link to bigger image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwjl0SErKySTMmkwZ21zOXhJSEU/edit?usp=sharing Yes but I have to know what that character is to replace it with some other character, perhaps vbCrLf

Comment: @DaveU: There is not method like Application.Clean atleast in my Outlook VBA.

Comment: For me your screen looks like a problem with your line breaks. Why are you replacing Chr(9) with vbCrLF? 9 stands for the _Tab_ character, line breaks are (system dependent) `10`, `13` or `10 13` (at least this are the most common ones. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).

Comment: Sometimes you can get lucky with the macro recorder.  Record macro, select the odd character, copy and do a find (cntrl+f), stop recording.  See if the macro distinguishes the code for that character.  Now you can do a replace.

Comment: Try this macro which converts a string, such as a cell value, to hex. `Public Sub DsplInHex(Stg As String)` `Dim Pos As Long` `For Pos = 1 To Len(Stg)` `Debug.Print Hex(AscW(Mid(Stg, Pos, 1))) & " ";` `Next` `Debug.Print` `End Sub`

Comment: May I see the Excel file? If yes, can you upload the same in www.wikisend.com and then share the link here?

Comment: I guess I assumed you'd be using Excel VBA

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Sure. File is here http://www.fileswap.com/dl/qTZpQEnsZq/

Comment: @PortlandRunner,sina Ok good suggestion. I will try that out when I get access to client's PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cells have the special character `Chr(160)`. Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Columns(4).Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Or in outlook, after this line `oWS.Cells(LastRow, "D") = Body`

Add this line

```
oWS.Cells(LastRow, "D").Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:="", LookAt:=2, _
SearchOrder:=1, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have sent updated version to client. Will let you know what happens